# Меню с логотипом не идут в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Не получается выставить меню и логотип в одну строку. Хотя два последних блока (лого и register now) стоят в строчку, а применить все это к навигации не получается.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Organic Fruit</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Rosario:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="menu"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li class="menu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </div>
                </nav>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/planet.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
               </div>

               <div class="offser-md-2 col-md-3">
                    register now
               </div>
                

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

```
a
    text-decoration: none       
.menu
    display: inline-block
    padding-right: 40px
    font-family: DM Sans
    font-weight: 400
    font-size: 18px
    line-height: 24px
    list-style-type: none
    a
        color: #222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получилась бутстрап-сетка, внутри `row` должны быть блоки с классами `col-*`. А Вы туда включили `nav` безо всяких классов, потому всё едет. Уберите лишний div внутри nav и задайте класс `col-md-5` самому nav:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-5">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/planet.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
           </div>

           <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-3">
                register now
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

p.s. И ещё у Вас опечатка - не `offser`, а `offset`.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь понял как это работает.